# Resend email confirmation in adxstudio portal

Tags: crm, adxstudio-portals

You can configure ADXStudio portal in a way that when someone registers an new account, an email confirmation will be sent. My question is that what is the easiest way to resend the confirmation email because sometimes confirmation emails do get lost and customers will want them to be resent. Thanks.